# Drupal 7 Cache Busting

Tags: caching, drupal-7, browser-cache

I have an external non-Drupal website members.example.com that sets a cookie if the audience member logs in on that site. It sets a cookie that is visible to the Drupal site that is:

$_COOKIE['name'] = 'John Smith';

I want to recognize that the members.example.com logged-in user has access to premium content on the Drupal site at www.example.com. I also want to great the logged-in member by name in the eyebrow section of the website.

The issue is, that after logging in the non-Drupal site members.example.com, and returning to the Drupal site www.example.com, Drupal is still caching a lot of stuff and doesn't recognize that the user now has the $_COOKIE['name'] set.

I have:

Set the cookie domain in settings.php to 'example.com'

Tried to bust the cache for anonymous Drupal users who also have the cookie this:

```
 /**
  * Implements hook_init()
  */
function caplogin_init() {

  // Check for cookie if it's set to 'loggedout':
  if (isset($_COOKIE['name'])) {
    if (strpos($_COOKIE['name'],'loggedout') !== FALSE) {
      // Log them out on the www site too:
      setcookie('name', '', 1, '/', '.example.com');
      global $user;
      if ($user->uid > 0) {
        user_logout();
      }
      $reason = 'Members server logout.';
      _caplogin_no_cache($reason);
      drupal_set_message(t('You have been logged out of the site. Thanks for visiting!'));
    }
    else {
      $reason = 'Member logged in internal server.';
      _caplogin_no_cache($reason);
    }
  }
}
```

and...

```
function _caplogin_no_cache($reason) {
    if (!$reason) {
      $reason = 'no-cache called by site functionality.';
    }
    drupal_add_http_header('X-DRCC-No-Cache-Reason', $reason);
    drupal_add_http_header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    drupal_add_http_header('Last-Modified', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
    drupal_add_http_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');
    drupal_add_http_header('Expires', 'Sat, 02 Jan 1971 00:00:00 GMT');
 }
```

I have also installed Devel module and (for testing) checked the ON checkbox for rebuilding the theme cache on every page load. No luck.

If you add a bogus query string it DOES bust the cache, e.g. http://www.example.com/?sdjaSDH

But the client needs the functionality where Drupal recognizes that the user has logged in the external members.example.com site.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this

```
$GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE;
```

help ?

You might need to add this code to hook_boot() or hook_init() with some switches of your desire.